# Proof that that $K=\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, ideals, differential-algebra

I am looking at the following part:

[image]

$$$$

---

[image]

$$$$

---

[image]

$$$$

---

[image]

$$$$

---

$$$$

I haven't really understood the proof...

We suppose that Grothendieck's problem stand and that almost all prime ideals of the algebraic number field $K$ are of degree one.

We want to show that $K=\mathbb{Q}$.

Why do we take $K=\mathbb{Q}(a)$ ?

Why does it stand that for each prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ of degree one there exists an integer $\alpha (\mathfrak{p})$ such that $\alpha=\alpha (\frak{p}) \pmod {\mathfrak{p}}$ ?

Answer (score 1):

We can assume $K=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ for some $\alpha$ by the [primitive element theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_element_theorem).

I'm not sure what degree means in this context; I'm guessing it means the degree of the residue field $\mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{p}$ over the subfield $\mathbb{Z}/(\mathfrak{p}\cap\mathbb{Z})$?  Assuming that, then for the degree to be $1$ means that $\mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{p}=\mathbb{Z}/(\mathfrak{p}\cap\mathbb{Z})$, and any element of the latter has an integral representative.  So if we consider $\alpha$ mod $\mathfrak{p}$, we can find some integer $\alpha(\mathfrak{p})$ that represents it modulo $\mathfrak{p}$.

Comment: But this way you're assuming that $\alpha \in \mathcal{O}_K$?

Comment: Alright, you can pretty much assume $\alpha \in \mathcal{O}_K$. If $\alpha\notin \mathcal{O}_K$, take the conductor $\frak{f} = \rm{Ann}_{\mathcal{O}_K}(\mathbb{Z}[\alpha])$. It is an ideal in $\mathcal{O}_K$, so there is $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ with $\mathfrak{f}\cap \mathbb{Z}=n\mathbb{Z}$, thus $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha] = \mathbb{Q}[n\alpha]$ and $n\alpha\in\mathcal{O}_K$, so you can take $n\alpha$ instead of $\alpha$ (and clearly $x^{\alpha}$ is algebraic iff $x^{n\alpha}$ is).

Comment: Oh, thanks, I did mistakenly assume that.